# Display each digit in a separate column in a row in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a column of data in binary values and I would like to split each digit of the number in the column into different cells across a row. How would I go about doing so? I saw the split function, but could not get it to work. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?

One of my example inputs:

```
1000111110100101111011110
1000110000100101000010000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this (you just change A2 to your cell):

```
=transpose(arrayformula(mid(A2,row(A1:offset(A1,len(A2),0)),1)))
```

For some rows (I limited text length with 30 char, you can change it):

```
=transpose(ARRAYFORMULA(mid(transpose(query(arrayformula(if(isnumber(A1:A)=true ,text(A1:A,"0"),A1:A)),"Select Col1 where Col1<>''")),row(A1:A30),1)))
```

Comment: But is there a way for this to work with arbitrary input column lengths?

Comment: This just will take the length of cell for example A2 with len(A2), but this will not work if column not available or used.

Comment: Say for instance I had three inputs (each on separate rows, in a column):


1000111110100101111011110
1000110000100101000010000
1000111110100101111011110


What would I need to change to make this work?
Is there a way to do it with an arbitrary row number?

Sorry if I am asking too many questions, I am just trying to understand what you are doing here.

Comment: 1000111110100101111011110 1000110000100101000010000 1000111110100101111011110 will give you 77 or more columns for each digit include space or cariage

Comment: Ok so if I am understanding this right, all the data would have to be in the same cell?

Comment: may be you must split first with =split(A2,char(10))

Comment: do you mean three inputs in sparate row?

Comment: Yeah, so that this would could be used over a larger spread sheet

Comment: Please try, I have added next formula

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, REPT("(.)", LEN(A1:A))))
```

[image: 0]